# Changing child div background by binding Jquery with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I would like to change the child's div background by clicking the parent div with the right mouse button. I have the following code:

```
<div data-bind="  event: { contextmenu: function(){$(this).children().css('background-color', 'red'); myfunction(); } }">
         <div> Something </div>
</div>
```

My function just runs fine but id doesn't do anything with the child div. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$($element).children()...
```

See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: thank you. I will accept this as right answer as soon as it lets me to do so.